# Does distinct_permutations in more_itertools have a sorting behavior?

Tags: python, sorting, graph

A [Halin graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halin_graph) is a graph constructed by embedding a tree with no vertex of degree two in the plane and then adding a cycle to join the tree’s leaves.

[image]

Recently, I posted on a  [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447090/is-there-an-algorithm-to-generate-non-isomorphic-halin-graphs/447101?noredirect=1#comment1155604_447101) about generating non-isomorphic Halin graphs of order 20. User Peter Taylor provided a nice answer. However, I found that his [Python code](https://oeis.org/A346779/a346779.py.txt) couldn't run on my Linux system and resulted in the following error.

> python3.10/site-packages/more_itertools/more.py" The error occurs at
> line 727 in the distinct_permutations function: items =
> sorted(iterable) TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of
> 'RootedTree' and 'RootedTree'

So, I believe **the issue lies in the presence of sorting** in `distinct_permutations` (in third-party libraries `more_itertools`).

As a result, I made some modifications. I replaced `distinct_permutations(self.children)` with `permutations(self.children)` and now the code runs, but it is **too slow**.

---

I try to add  `def __lt__(self, other): return self.size() < other.size()` in class RootedTree.  The speed is good, but the data generated is different from the data obtained in [A346779](https://oeis.org/A346779) starting from n=19. Therefore, modifying the source code in such a way may introduce potential issues regarding the correctness of generating Halin graphs.

I am not sure how to obtain the correct sequence of [A346779](https://oeis.org/A346779). Despite having a lengthy discussion with Peter Taylor,  but he insists that his code runs fine on their computer. I feel a bit confused about this situation.

Comment: Source code here: https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#distinct_permutations. It does indeed use `sorted` as well as `<` between items in the iterable.

Comment: @slothrop Yes, that's correct. So I informed Peter Taylor about this reason, but to my surprise, he still claim that it runs on his terminal without any issues. I'm not sure if it's due to version differences. However, even when I rolled back to version more-itertools 5.00, there is still a sorting behavior present.

Comment: The sorting was added [back in 2020](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/commit/3649b878610372b4cfb6074d21a4bb43b1c1b849) in the update that added support for the `r` parameter. It sounds like Peter Taylor is on an old version of more_itertools.

Comment: more_itertools 5.0.0 shouldn't have the sorting, though. [Here's the 5.0.0 code.](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools/blob/5.0.0/more_itertools/more.py#L543)

Comment: @user2357112 I suppose you could extend your comment and post it as an answer

Comment: @user2357112 I use`pypy3` and `more_itertools 8.0.0` and everything is Ok.  But `Python3`  with `more_itertools 8.0.0` is not Ok... haven't figured out why yet (I'm not sure if a virtual environment hasn't been set up).